# Centering controls in UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp, controls

I'm trying to center a textblock in my app window. I tried this code inside the textblock's Loaded event handler:

```
    private void textBlock1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("textBlock1_Loaded");
        double textBlockWidth = textBlock1.Width;
        double textBlockHeight = textBlock1.Height;
        double gridWidth = grid1.Width;
        double gridHeight = grid1.Height;
        double leftRightMargin_center = (gridWidth - textBlockWidth) / 2;
        double topBottomMargin_center = (gridHeight - textBlockHeight) / 2;
        double topMargin_needed = topBottomMargin_center - 25;
        double bottomMargin_needed = topBottomMargin_center + 25;
        double leftMargin_needed = leftRightMargin_center;
        double rightMargin_needed = leftRightMargin_center;
        textBlock1.Margin = new Thickness(leftMargin_needed, topMargin_needed, rightMargin_needed, leftMargin_needed);
    }
```

Here's the resulting app:

[image: the resulting app]

Am I doing something wrong in here? And yes, that's the only question I have in this thread.

Comment: what kind of container control is the textblock in?

Comment: See, now, in WPF I'd just use HorizontalAlignment=Center in the XAML, but I'm an asshole.  Normally, in any XAML-based UI, you don't have to do any of this Windows Forms-style insanity within your codebehind.  What does your XAML look like?

Comment: @KenTucker it's just inside a grid

Comment: @Will I want it to be in my codebehind

Comment: You want to do it the hardest way. That's ... admirable?

Comment: @AlsanAli why don't you set `textBlock1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;`

Comment: @Will The reason I don't want the XAML way is because I need it to be custom. I want TWO controls to be centered, and one control (the TextBlock) should be above the other control (a TextBox). Is there a XAML way of doing this? If there is, I'll be glad to use it.

Comment: @AlsanAli To place two control at the same spot you can use `Grid` and simply place your control inside the `Grid`

Comment: @VijayNirmal I'm not trying to place controls at the same spot. I'm trying to place one control above the other, and both of them should be centered.

Comment: @AlsanAli So one control should hide the other. Am I right?

Comment: @VijayNirmal https://imgur.com/a/543jC

Comment: Look, there are **container** controls that specifically exist to align their children how you want.  In this case, nesting your two controls inside of a <StackPanel> then setting the alignment on *that* would have been **all you needed to do**. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel

Comment: @Will oh, thanks, didn't know :P

Comment: When asking a question in future, make sure to always state what you are attempting to do as well as what you did and why it isn't working. There's always a chance that you're going at it the hard way, and someone can suggest an easier solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `StackPanel`

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Top Text" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Bottom Text" Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```